# Detecting last mode of operation in an NMI handler

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing an NMI handler in an LKM. I would like to know the mode(user or kernel) of operation during the NMI fire. Is there any kernel flag to denote that? I am running Linux 4.18.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine if cpu was in user or kernel mode by value of CS register, which is saved on stack by CPU in addition to RIP, RSP, SS etc.

Stack layout of interrupts is described in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 ArchitecturesSoftware Developer’s ManualVolume 3A:System Programming Guide, Part](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf)  Section 6.12.1

In kernel mode, saved CS value is __KERNEL_CS, in user mode - __USER_CS.

Code of default kernel nmi handler actually does this in /arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S:

```
ENTRY(nmi)
...
testb   $3, CS-RIP+8(%rsp)
jz  .Lnmi_from_kernel
```